# "Unable to Relay" error while sending mail from Struts application using exchange server

Tags: tomcat, struts2, exchange-server, jakarta-mail, emailrelay

i am working on a web application using struts2 and Apache Tomcat 6 as the web-server. In the application i am trying to send some emails and i am using JavaMail for this. The problem is that i am not being able to send mails to email addresses that are outside my company domain. I can send mails to email addresses that are in my company domain.

The confusing thing is that, if i run the JavaMail program outside my web application as a single/separate Java program then mails are going to address that are in outside domain. The problem arises in my web application when there is no change in the JavaMail code. Please help.

JavaMail code

```
        final String username = "mymail@abc.com";
        final String password = "password";    

        Properties props = new Properties();  
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "myExchangeMailServer"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");              
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable", "true");

        Session session =  
            Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);  
                }  
            }); 

        Transport trans=null;
        try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);             
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(username);  
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);       
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com")};           
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, address);  
        msg.setSubject("subject");  
        msg.setText("Test mail. This is actual message");
        trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
        trans.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME,username,password);
        msg.saveChanges();
        trans.sendMessage(msg, address);            
        }
        catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Error stacktrace

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.1
DEBUG: not loading file: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\javamail.providers
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\javamail.providers (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: not loading file: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "myExchangeMailServer", port 25, isSSL false
220 myExchangeMailServer Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sat, 26 Apr 2014 09:50:42 +0530
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "myExchangeMailServer", port: 25

EHLO myComputerName
250-myExchangeMailServer Hello [myIPAddress]
250-SIZE
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH NTLM
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250-XRDST
250 XSHADOW
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-ANONYMOUSTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XEXCH50", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XRDST", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XSHADOW", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<mymail@abc.com>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
RCPT TO:<xyz@gmail.com>
550 5.7.1 Unable to relay
DEBUG SMTP: Invalid Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   xyz@gmail.com
DEBUG SMTP: Sending failed because of invalid destination addresses
RSET
250 2.0.0 Resetting
  javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
 nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1294)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:635)
at common.sendMail.<init>(sendMail.java:60)
at backEnd.admin.post(admin.java:169)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1145)
... 72 more
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
 nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1294)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:635)
at common.sendMail.<init>(sendMail.java:60)
at backEnd.admin.post(admin.java:169)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1145)
... 72 more
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
```

And this is the stacktrace if I run the sendMail program separately

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "myExchangeMailServer", port 25, isSSL false
220 myExchangeMailServer Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sat, 26 Apr 2014 09:48:08 +0530
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "myExchangeMailServer", port: 25

EHLO myComputerName
250-myExchangeMailServer Hello [myIPAddress]
250-SIZE
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH NTLM
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250-XRDST
250 XSHADOW
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-ANONYMOUSTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XEXCH50", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XRDST", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XSHADOW", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG SMTP: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
DEBUG SMTP: mechanism DIGEST-MD5 not supported by server
DEBUG NTLM: type 1 message: 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 01 00 00 00 03 A2 00 00 00 00 00 00 23 00 00 00 03 00 03 00 20 00 00 00 31 37 32 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH NTLM command trace suppressed
DEBUG NTLM: type 3 message: 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 03 00 00 00 18 00 18 00 7A 00 00 00 18 00 18 00 92 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 34 00 34 00 40 00 00 00 06 00 06 00 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AA 00 00 00 01 82 00 00 69 00 74 00 68 00 65 00 6C 00 70 00 64 00 65 00 73 00 6B 00 40 00 62 00 63 00 70 00 6C 00 69 00 6E 00 64 00 69 00 61 00 2E 00 63 00 6F 00 2E 00 69 00 6E 00 31 00 37 00 32 00 05 8A 00 03 60 D0 B1 2C B4 FB FE 2F 1C E1 E8 B6 52 E7 B6 45 47 83 01 7B 17 9A 1C A9 BA D6 2E F5 93 2E 6B B2 BF F1 D3 B6 42 3B FC AA 48 CB 75 2C 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH NTLM succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<mymail@abc.com>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
RCPT TO:<xyz@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   xyz@gmail.com
DATA
354 
From: mymail@abc.com
To: xyz@gmail.com
Message-ID: <940452025.0.1398485768836.JavaMail.myName@myComputerName>
Subject: subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test mail. This is actual message
.
250 2.6.0 <940452025.0.1398485768836.JavaMail.myName@myComputerName> [InternalId=1422607] Queued mail for delivery
```

I don't understand why the same program runs separately but not within my web application. I have included the same mail.jar file in both. Do i need to make any change in my web.xml file or in my apache server configuration.

A telnet session with the mail server returned this:

[image]

Comment: Is it the same machine where you are running both the programs??

Comment: Yes, the same machine.

Comment: Try changing the dependency as @Bill Shanon suggested. But I suspect authentication has failed in your first case. Thus the mail seems to be coming from and external source which is again attempted to be sent to an external address and thus `Unable to relay for <address>` error. More details at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#norelay

Comment: Try setting `mail.debug.auth` to `true` in your webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using JavaMail 1.4.1 when it doesn't work and JavaMail 1.4.7 when it does work.  You probably want to use the latest [JavaMail 1.5.1 release](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) in both cases.  That will almost certainly fix your problem.

Also, there's no property named "mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable".  I don't know where you got that from but it's completely bogus.

The "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" property is correct, but your server doesn't seem to support STARTTLS so it's not being used; you're sending your authentication information in the clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and your help. It was a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. I uploaded the newer JavaMail jar and it ran perfectly. I have also removed the TTLS and SSL properties as the server doesn't use it. I can send the mails to outside domain now but delivery to Gmail is delayed while mails to other domains are delivered instantly. Anything that can be done to solve this?

Comment: You probably need to look at the log files on your mail server to find out why delivery is delayed.  It may be an anti-spam feature in Gmail.